# List Tomcat connections using JMX

Tags: java, tomcat, jmx

Is there a way to list all connections per deployed jar in Tomcat?

I found this code to list all applications:

```
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://31.181.71.213:9999/jmxrmi");
JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);
MBeanServerConnection server = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
Set<ObjectName> names = server.queryNames(new ObjectName("Catalina:type=Host,*"), null);
Set<String> hostNames = new HashSet<String>();

for (ObjectName on : names)
{
    hostNames.add(on.getKeyProperty("host"));
}

for (String str : hostNames)
{
    ObjectName[] webapps = (ObjectName[]) server.getAttribute(new ObjectName("Catalina:type=Host,host=" + str), "children");
    for (ObjectName ob : webapps)
    {
        String[] appSpl = ob.getKeyProperty("name").split("//localhost");
        // webappNames.add(appSpl[1]);
        System.out.println("Deployed application " + appSpl[1]);
    }
}
```

But how I can also list the network connections?

Comment: deployed *jar* or *war*? Also, are you looking for *incoming* connections or *outgoing* (e.g. HTTP-Handlers or Database - just as example). But more importantly, as this seems to not gain enough attention: What problem do you actually want to solve with this solution - maybe there's a different solution if we understand the underlying problem.

Comment: I want to list for jars and wars

Comment: Come on. You did read the comment past the first question mark, right? Also, I thought that you'd have a typo with jar/war, but now that you state you're interested in both: Please describe the semantics that you expect from "connections per jar", in addition to the information requested above. Please edit your question with the information, rather than adding a short comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache ActiveMQ is what you are looking for!

You can achieve the connection statistics using the `ActiveMQ MBeans -  Connection`

Have a look at the [Apache ActiveMQ JMX](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html)

Comment: this is add-on for Tomcat?

Comment: @PeterPenzov its a message broker, find more info at wikipedia [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_ActiveMQ]